# custom raw compression

Tags: wavelet, image-compression, video-compression, sparse-model

I'm planning to acquire between 50k and 200k image per day with a 50MPixels (or 68MPixels or 130MPixels) sensor; I'll be acquiring the raw data (10 or 12 or 14 bits) from the sensor through SLVS-EC and create a raw file of my own design. The raw bitrate from the sensor may go up to 75.2 Gbps.

I may have to store 50k-250k images per day (eg., 17.5TB if 250k images are 70MB-50MPixels each). I need to keep high quality images (in particular, colors must remain accurate and textures fully detailed, hence the lossless or only light loss and nothing below 10 bits per channel), and a flexibility in edition (hence the raw).

Also images will share a lot, since I may have 2-24Hz framerate at capture; also a first processing will drop (delete) between 10% and 50% of images, so a keyframe based compression may not be suitable.

Since I need to keep the storage cost as low as possible without doing too hard compression (maybe go below 30-50MB per raw image). I'm planning to allow compression within this raw file, this compression can be lossless or lightly lossy. I'm thinking about wavelet and auto learnt dictionaries (patchs and sparse coding) for the compression, but this is not a requirement.

I will not release any sdk or raw image, so there are no need or requirement on the standard and adoption side. I'll very likely use an FPGA for signal processing (up to 75.2Gbps from the sensor), since I need very high IO and fast signal processing, and the whole package will be embedded, and as compact as possible and reasonnably light (say less than 1-2kg).

About the images, it will be natural environment with natural day light; it may include shadows and sky with sun, and hence high dynamic, but also rich (high frequency) textures which must be preserved. So likely I won't add further denoising, but I want to keep the fexibility with color processing: in particular the ability to change the signal amplification and the white/black balance.

Do you have thoughts and pieces of advice about the compression strategy for this raw format ? In particular do you think video compression algorithms (eg., HEVC) could be adapted to raw bayered data ?

Comment: none of this suggests an FPGA is the right approach! You need to store data on a relatively benign rate  on mass storage – sounds like a job for PC-style general purpose hardware, i.e., desktop/workstation/server CPUs. So, if you need the FPGA for anything else, OK, but trying to do the processing on the FPGA will both be much more complicated, and much more expensive, than doing it on a CPU.

Comment: There might be sense, under some very specific applications, to build an FPGA-based accelerator for some parts of the signal processing. For what you've written so far, this isn't necessary nor would it be productive. So, you'll have to tell us, really, what your system is for, what the things limiting it are, *why* you need to use an FPGA (because you'll have some PC-sized processing in this system, anyways, in all devices that store these amounts of data), and so on. Please clarify! Your question isn't very well-defined without, I'm afraid.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for all the comments. I edited in order to improve clarity. If your read the OP again, you will find that I did not used "need to use FPGA", but instead "likely", the same way I used "keyframes may not be suitable".

Comment: Doing "something" in MATLAB/Python may cost X. If so, I think that doing the same thing in clean, fast, tested C is at least (licking my finger) 10X. Doing the same in native fpga logic might well be another 10X. If the application calls for the speed and/or efficiency afforded by low level tools, then you need to invest in the knowledge/coworkers that is required. In many cases, if you can buy yourself out of the problem by running an expensive fan-cooled PC, that may allow you to focus on other, more pressing tasks.

Comment: Plus: this calls for incremental encoding, an inherently serial thing, mostly bound by memory speed–not sure how an FPGA is going to be faster at comparable wattage for that part of the task; might be faster for some integral transforms, but developing anything that exceeds the performance of a PC that's not already available as intellectual property to just drop in your design will take developer months to years, depending on your experience developing high-throughput signal processing FPGA logic. I really don't think doing the compression on an FPGA is something you'd consider at this stage.

Comment: @Soleil interesting edits! Could you tell us about the nature of the images? That pretty much is what defines what compression approach you'd take. An example image (or image excerpt) might be worth a thousand words!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Unfortunately I don't have the possibility to share images; the machine is in planning phase. It will be natural environment with natural day light; it may include shadows and sky with sun, and hence high dynamic, but also rich (high frequency) textures which must be preserved.

Comment: @KnutInge Thanks for the suggestions. Do you know that from matlab you can export a function into c code, as well as c++ code into HDL ? This can be very helpful, however sometimes it less expensive to write directly with the final constraints knowing the specific architecture (eg., c cuda).

Comment: @MarcusMüller The point about high throughput FPGA is interesting, I'm aware of this and it will be studied, this is kind of off-topic since I'm focusing here on compression strategy for raw data. I can always write uncompressed raw (on the embedded device)  and asynchronously/later have it compressed in the datacenter. For sure the existing tech and bandwidth will decide about what can be done during the image creation and writing. I'm aware a good Threadripper or good gpu(s) may be better for the task, this will be decided later.

Comment: I have tried auto generating c code from Matlab. I have found it less useful, but that could be down to my requirements: prototype in matlab, make it a product in C. The C code needs to be fast, readable and maintainable for other developers not wanting to touch matlab. While auto generated C code should be thought of as «intermediate compiler code»: it will produce the desired binary, but any changes should be done to the matlab definition. Thus it makes sense to manually rewrite in C. For a single-dev lab task, the situation could be very different.

Comment: @KnutInge Sometimes, trying to use a bad (poorly written, poorly maintained, hardly compilable/installable) c++ library is more expensive than writing by a good engineer the c++ or cuda code. Anyway all this is interesting but off-topic since I'm focused here on the compression strategy, which can have much more financial impact than hardware and development cost on long term (imagine filling a 18TB HDD at 250EUR per day without compression).

Comment: There are raw codecs out there. Apple have something called ProRes RAW, REDCODE can compress by 18:1. You will probably find that lossless intra compression can do something like 2:1 compression on a varied set of input, that specialized «raw» codecs have moderate compression, while you need something like h26x with inter compression to have 100:1 compression with decent quality. So it depends on how much of a pain storage cost it to you, what you need to retain in the images, and how much time/competence you have to tailor a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Raw files are (ideally) the raw readout of a sensor. Suitable for research, or if you want to eek out all possible information from a sensor using fancy offline processing. Now or in 10 years. In some cases, you might not need all of the information contained in a full raw image, but be satisfied with having maksimum exposure freedom - ie to avoid tonemapping/tonecurves baked into something like a jpeg preprocessing.

Do you specifically need to store it in Bayer format, or could you do debayer and use some off the shelf YCbCr 4:2:0 compression? What kind of compute platform do you have between sensor and storage (a PC?)

If file size is a major concern, something like x264 with >8 bits and high-ish bitrate is going to be hard to beat with home-grown tools in terms of quality per bit or quality per cycle unless you have very specific requirements or a lot of skill and time.

Edit:
Responding to some of the comments below.
I would borrow a nice camera, take two snapshots of the scene in question, read the raw files using dcraw or some similar tool and import into matlab/python.

Then you can play with debayer, fixed whitebalance (?), whitepoint and blackpoint and gamma (I think that h26x tends to be limited to 10 bits, but note that this is usually nonlinear quantization - more resolution in the blacks where it matters more). Finally, do a 3x3 matrix to a pseudo YCbCr format, save and pass it to a lossy encoder. Observe the file size of the first frame (intra) and the second (inter). That tells you a lot about how compressible the stream will be.

Then check the output file, carefully reversing the steps above. Check if quality is sufficient for your needs. Be prepared to do some fiddling until the stars align.

Comment: Did you mean x265 ? I'll have an FPGA for signal processing (OP updated).

Comment: If you are filming something like a security camera, vanilla compression w/inter prediction may do well even with every second frame deleted. I dont think x264 or x265 are available as fpga code, but perhaps the fpga manufacturer provides libraries with standard video compression? Or are you running pure software on some hard cpu block? Doing cutting edge video compression in native fpga sounds like real work…

Comment: Well, I also prefer to avoid video compression with keyframes, but since there will be a lot in common, I may think of a sparse dictionary common to several images, so I avoid keyframes and I can drop the 10-50% of images easily, and still have a wavelet based comrpession. x264/x265 are subsequently rather opted out. The problems is that it may be too much "CPU bound" since I need to keep a good write speed.

Comment: where does the need for wavelets arise from? 30 years of compression research suggest wavelets are not the tool of choice here. Also, note you're coming up with new requirements in every comment. This suggests you need to fundamentally rewrite your question to actually explain your constraints, rather than letting them negate an answer after people have spent time on answering! I, for example, would have an answer to complement Knut's answer, but I will not spend half an hour writing it down unless I understand **why** you're having these rather surprising constraints –

Comment: doing the work now before you explained your constraints and objectives is almost certain to be met with "oh I haven't mentioned yet another constraint that rules out your answer", and as mentioned, the constraints (FPGA, wavelet compression, no keyframes) are surprising and counter-productive for what you've written in requirements now.

Comment: @KnutInge I could debayer, but I'm loosing the raw flexibility for edition; don't I ? About the platform, no particular requirement except the potential bitrate and the need to have something embedded.

Comment: @KnutInge About the security camera and prediction point, the image will be permanently changing and un predicted, but I can predict, given the image content, if the image should be dropped, but I cannot predict if the image should be kept (only that the "drop" predition is negative). So this dropping will very likely happen on debayered RGB image (unless I learn an "AI" from the raw files).

Comment: If you debayer, you loose some freedom to do fancy debayer, and exotic joint denoise/deconvolution/debayer algorithms. You can still keep the color representation native for full flexibility in color corr/white balance. You can still keep a linear tone curve meaning that exposure correction and highlight recovery can do its thing. Note that having a linear gamma may reduce compression efficiency of jpeg/h264 somewhat.

Comment: @KnutInge Very likely I won't do binning, and I hope to avoid denoise computations (the sensor does that already "a bit"). The "native color representation" is important; are you saying I can keep this after debayering ? I edited the OP: could I used a selection of HEVC algorithms on a bayered or debayered data and keep the native color representation ?

Comment: See updates to my answer above.